# Event Handler C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Mi problema es que al subscribir un evento se procesa el mismo metodo multiples veces en paralelo. La verdad no entiendo como funciona el manejo de events.

Les dejo el codigo:

Asi hago el unregisted y registed desde un metodo

```
    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext) //Esto es porque trabajo con WPF entonces registro el event cuando ingresa a la pantalla
    {
         ...
         KioskHardware.HardwareDetectionEvent -= KioskHardware_HardwareDetectionEvent;
         KioskHardware.HardwareDetectionEvent += KioskHardware_HardwareDetectionEvent;
         ...
    }
```

Llamo a este método pero se procesa un montón de veces de manera simultanea.

```
    void KioskHardware_HardwareDetectionEvent(object sender, HardwareDetectionEventArgs e)
    {

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
        {
            ...
        }), null);

    }
```

Definicion de KioskHardware:

```
    [Import]
    public Kiosk KioskHardware;
```

Kiosk.cs

```
public delegate void HardwareDetectionEventHandler(object sender, HardwareDetectionEventArgs e);

[Export]
public class Kiosk : IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    ...
    public event HardwareDetectionEventHandler HardwareDetectionEvent;
    ...
}
```

Cualquier idea de como solucionarlo o de como funcionan los events es bien recibida.

Saludos.

Comment: donde registras el evento? porque lo registras y lo desregistras?

Comment: Lo registro en la misma clase donde se encuentra KioskHardware_HardwareDetectionEvent pero en otro metodo, no lo agregue porque no servia de mucho pero si queres lo agrego

Comment: si cambias `KioskHardware.HardwareDetectionEvent -= KioskHardware_HardwareDetectionEvent;` por `KioskHardware.HardwareDetectionEvent = null` el resultado es el mismo?

Comment: Porque haces el registro en OnNavigatedTo y no en el load de la pagina?

Comment: Esto fue hecho por otro programador esta trabajado con el framework Prism, tengo un xaml que es la vista, xaml.cs que es el codigo de la vista y un controlador que es desde estoy laburando esto.

Comment: Ahi probe Juan y el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: ok.. si tenes un framework es **muy** importante que lo aclares...

Comment: Ok. Esto se lo llama mvvm al modelo y lo implemento con wpf. El OnNavigatedTo es lo primero que ejecuta al entrar al controller y OnNavigatedFrom lo ultimo que ejecuta al salir.

Comment: Si estas usando `Prism`, debes tener en cuenta que las interfaces declaradas y los servicios pueden ser accedidas siempre que se den de alta en un container (imagino que usara un `UnityContainer`), esto conlleva que pueden apuntarse/lanzar eventos desde múltiples partes del código (esa es la gracia del container) y debes tener controlado todo esto ya que si entra varias veces en un evento es porque se esta lanzando varias veces.